# Windows Explorer making thousands of registry reads per second, slows computer to a halt

Tags: windows-7, performance, windows-explorer, windows-registry, procmon

This is a Windows 7 64-bit install. Towards the end of the day, all of the sudden, their computer will grind to a halt. It stops responding for a few seconds while performing any action.

I ran ProcMon while the problem was occurring, but I'm not sure what the problem is. The logs indicate that Explorer.exe is reading from the registry thousands of times per second, but there doesn't appear to be any reason for it to be doing so.

The slowdown happens randomly, in many different programs the users uses, but always around the end of the day. It goes on for a long period of time, but can be cured immediately by a reboot.

I have trace logs available at http://sdrv.ms/13TAX56

Comment: Do you have any dodgy shell extensions installed?

Comment: Not as far as I know. I have not noticed anything weird in there.

Comment: Try disabling your antivirus and see if that's the culprit.  Long shot but you never know.

Comment: where are the logs? upload them and insert a link to your post.

Comment: I uploaded the logs to my SkyDrive. Please let me know if they are not opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This client uses a paid version of ESET anti-virus. We reformatted and reinstalled Windows, which included installing a fully up-to-date ESET install. The slowness continued.

We disabled ESET, and like magic, the computer functioned normally from then on. Thanks, ESET! :S

Let it be known that I suggested disabling ESET, but my team had already started the nuke and pave option. When it rains, it pours.